# Duplicate AndroidManifest.xml in bin directory?

Tags: android, android-manifest, duplication

I just upgraded to a latest ADT and seems a quite a bit has changed (for the better).

Just created a new project and looked into the `bin` directory of my project and I see a `AndroidManifest.xml` file that seems to be an exact duplicate as the one in the root of the project.

Changes to the root manifest file seem to also seem to automatically reflect on the one in `bin`

What gives? Why is there a duplicate manifest?  Can't seem to find any documentation for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the result of the new **manifestmerger.enabled** property.

You can use it to merge library project manifest files into the including project's manifest.

The resulting manifest will be in your /bin directory.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! For those wondering, this gets set to true in the project.properties file.

Comment: @Benito Bertoli can you give an example of why you want to do this?

Comment: @committedandroider This can help you if you have activities or receivers declared in your library project's manifest. They would be merged with your current project's manifest, so you wouldn't have to declare them again.

Answer (score 1):

When your project builds it creates a copy of itself for execution in the bin folder, you can ignore everything in the build folder as it doesn't require editing directly by you. You will also find copies of .class files, compiled from your java equivalents, a .dex file, and all of your drawable resources.

The only AndroidManifest.xml you have to worry about is the one in your root project directory